# How do I increase my village's income in Ninja Village?

Tags: ninja-village

This seems like a simple question, but I'm lost on how to actually significantly increase output; even as I gain more villagers I don't seem to gain much more money per month.

I've built multiple workshops and lumber/ore depots.  I've got plenty of supplies but my stores are always being sold out (even though I only have one of each).  Is there something I'm missing to from this equation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the best way I've learned that improves income.  Following the suggestions from [this thread](http://adeptgamer.com/forum/threads/a-general-guide-and-direction-for-the-lost-and-worried.594/page-2), I managed to hit an amazing income of 20,000 gold per month near the end game.

Here are the key points:

1. Limit your pathing to be the most basic as possible.  In the setup, each shop has exactly 1 path from the workshop.  The distance traveled between workshop to shop is extremely small, as is the distance from workshop to resources.
2. Don't be afraid to separate off sections of your village.  There really is no reason to have a completely connected village.
3. Abuse effect boosting squares.  Don't be afraid to stack up multiple wells, flower gardens, trees, etc until you can afford the best versions of those items.
4. Put your highly productive ninjas in the houses that are near the production areas.  For the ones I like to use in battle, I keep them off on the hills to the top right area of the map.  You don't need pathing to houses as ninjas will walk to them no matter where they are, but they can't come out of them if there are no roads next to them (not a big deal for the super low work ninjas anyway like Jon).
5. Make sure you do the emperor training ground early to get the scythe, tengui, and pony.  Those are huge boosts to work stat.  Also, give the mushroom hat (there are only 2  in the entire game) to any work you get that has strong back (like momosuke).  I believe a few others can learn strong back when you level them up high enough.

Here are the screenshots of the final setup, note how everything is sectioned off and each workshop and the shops are completely detached from the rest of the village and can only be accessible via the 1 square path from each workshop.

"Lower Village:"
[image]

"Upper Village:"
[image]

Note the lower/upper halves are completely separated from each other with no way across.

Early game, you should have farms in the spots where you have lumber and ore buildings and trees, and instead of the fancy good shop, you'll have the tea shop and/or tofu shop.

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea that villagers could move through workshops without a road!  My setup right now has a road in front of everything.

Comment: @DanielLew technically, there's a road on each side, so they enter one side of the building and exit the other. :)

Comment: Adding stairs between the "sections" makes the AI go haywire, it seems.  Blocking it off like that mitigates that quite well.

Comment: So there's also no reason to stock one of each shop, right?  Just pick the most expensive shop and everyone buys that?  :P

Comment: @DanielLew yup, that's exactly right, though if you want to go for a high score, you get points for every item you research so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks, between this and the thread you linked it has a ton of good info filling in the gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: One of the few things I don't agree on in that thread is wasting your main character in a new game plus to copy shishimaru.  Kimura does a good enough job as an archer that I feel the MC is far better off duplicating Inuzuka's bulletproof ability.  Between the MC, her, Nishizawa (who learns bulletproof very late), and the kairo armor you get from beating tokugawa, your army is 80% impervious to bullets.